# FFMPEG - Single video file multiple audio files stream to YouTube

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming

Right now I have a working stream with:

`ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -re -i video/base_video_file.mp4 -loglevel warning -c:v libx264 -b:v 2M -c:a copy -strict -2 -flags +global_header -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -bufsize 2100k -f flv YT_URL/YT_KEY`

How could I use a single file as the video source and multiple audio files as the audio source and then have it all as the stream loop?

Comment: @llogan I want to have one single output stream so the video part of it is a single mp4 file and the audio part of it is a list of multiple consecutive mp3 files, all in a loop.

Comment: @llogan the only change I had to make to the .txt file was to add `ffconcat version 1.0` as the first line and `file 'input.txt'` as the last one, `-stream_loop -1` won't be necessary there because the concat will start again once the last line (the file itself) is reached.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make `input.txt` containing:

   ```
   file 'input1.mp3'
   file 'input2.mp3'
   ```

   All inputs must be the same format, sample rate, and channel layout.
2. Run `ffmpeg`:

   ```
   ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -re -i video.mp4 -stream_loop -1 -re -f concat -i input.txt -map 0:v -map 1:a -c:v libx264 -vf format=yuv420p -b:v 2M -bufsize 4M -maxrate 2M -g 50 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -flags +global_header -f flv YT_URL/YT_KEY
   ```

See the [concat demuxer documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat) for more info.